# i need help on parsing json url on php

Tags: php, json

Here is the json content:

```
{
   "success":true,
    "data":"{\"campaign_name\":\"helloworld\",\"download_link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/google.com\\\/accesskey\\\/getfile\\\/m-spqn-e61-2aef2575a0b5250354f2b0fda033e703?token=HUSYjdC5jyJskXUHiKn13l1A1BaAjH2R&dcma=5ecceb0522bcd0db\",\"link\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.lol.com\\\/remove\\\/remove.php\"}",
    "message":null
}
```

I'm looking to get the value of download_link. How can I do that?

This is what I tried:

```
<?php
$jsndata = {"success":true,"data":"{\"campaign_name\":\"helloworld\",\"download_link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/google.com\\\/accesskey\\\/getfile\\\/m-spqn-e61-2aef2575a0b5250354f2b0fda033e703?token=HUSYjdC5jyJskXUHiKn13l1A1BaAjH2R&dcma=5ecceb0522bcd0db\",\"link\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.lol.com\\\/remove\\\/remove.php\"}","message":null};
$jsn = json_decode($jsndata,true);

$temperatureMin = $jsn['data'][6]['download_link'];
echo $temperatureMin;
 ?>
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried this?

Comment: the code not working well, can you please give me the right code to extract the value of download_link from the $jsndata

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please define `not working well`. What do you get, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a json object containing another serialized json object.

Decode the first object, get the second serialized object and decode that:

```
$jsndata = '{
    "success":true,
    "data":"{\"campaign_name\":\"helloworld\",\"download_link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/google.com\\\/accesskey\\\/getfile\\\/m-spqn-e61-2aef2575a0b5250354f2b0fda033e703?token=HUSYjdC5jyJskXUHiKn13l1A1BaAjH2R&dcma=5ecceb0522bcd0db\",\"link\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.lol.com\\\/remove\\\/remove.php\"}",
    "message":null
}';

// Decode the main json object
$jsn = json_decode($jsndata,true);

// Since 'data' is another serialized object, you need to decode that as well:
$data = json_decode($jsn['data'], true);

// Now you can access the contents of 'data'
echo $data['download_link'];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/1PcQp

Comment: @adminjokmark - If it solved your issue, please mark it as accepted so other users know it's been resolved.

Comment: @adminjokmark - No. I don't know Perl and I'm not a free coding service. Make some research and attempts, and if you run into something specific issue that you can't solve while trying, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
- quotes around your JSON
- to remove the quotes around the inner object

$jsndata = '{"success":true,"data":{\"campaign_name\":\"helloworld\",\"download_link\":\"https:\\\/\\\/google.com\\\/accesskey\\\/getfile\\\/m-spqn-e61-2aef2575a0b5250354f2b0fda033e703?token=HUSYjdC5jyJskXUHiKn13l1A1BaAjH2R&dcma=5ecceb0522bcd0db\",\"link\":\"http:\\\/\\\/www.lol.com\\\/remove\\\/remove.php\"},"message":null}' ;
```

And you need to remove the `[6]` from your array access:

```
$temperatureMin = $jsn['data']['download_link'];
```

Comment: the return is empty, no data extract from the specific field

Comment: @adminjokmark, I replaced those two lines of code and it works when I run it. I'm not sure what you may be doing.